# Invalid cast while sending expression as a parameter to where

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a get function in my generic repository that receives an Expression so I don't have to write different function to filter by different attributes.

repo

```
  public async Task<IQueryable<T>> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return  databaseContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);
        }
```

controller

```
repositoryWrapper.ImageRepository.Get(x => x.ImageId == id)
//where id and x.ImageId are int types
```

But I receive this error when calling it

*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Single'.*

**INFO**

Is this approach better then simply return all the objects and then performing the query?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Single'.: well that's pretty much self explanatory? Don't pass int to filter on a decimal field, use cast / convert

Comment: Is this approach better then simply return all the objects and then performing the query: what if you had 100^12 entries. how would that perform?

Comment: yes, it was a mapping error. Regarding the efficenty. But what happens when tha database grows and you have a lot of rows in one table. Isn't it this approach better?

Comment: It is of course better to filter on DB side